# How to do Custom Rounding in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to round values like

2.50 -> 2

2.51 -> 3

When I apply ROUND(2.50) it gives 3 but it should be 2 in my case

How can I manage this in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want the function [`CEILING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling) like this:

```
CEILING(x - 0.5)
```